# initiate windows script or command on a windows host from linux ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting, windows, putty

Is there a way to run a script or command on a windows server from a linux server. I have searched but can't seem to find a simple solution.

Comment: Please define what you consider a **simple** solution.

Comment: like a one or two line command that I can put inside of a shell script. I dont mind installing a utility or some software on my linux server if needed.

Comment: I would install an ssh server on the windows machine and then use ssh from your linux machine

Comment: The windows OS guys wouldnt allow it. I will try out to winexe as mentioned below... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch windows command from Linux using winexe
It is like psexec but from Linux using RPC

```
./winexe -U user%password //192.168.0.1 ipconfig
```

or

```
./winexe --authentication-file=FILE //192.168.0.1 'cmd.exe /c echo "this is running on windows"'
```

Source: https://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, Ill have to download winexe but it should work.